# Trying to set parent on a telerik dialog control in order to use a behavior

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I'm trying to set the parent of a dialog that does not currently have one. Using the `this.Parent = ...` gives me the following error:

> Property or indexer 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Parent' cannot be assigned to -- it's read only.

Problem is that I need to set the parent in order for the behavior, which in this case is a on-screen keyboard, to work.

Any suggestions as to how I should go about setting this property?

UPDATE (from comment):

The code is being invoked by a `ICommand ChangePasswordCommand` which again is called from a binding in the xaml:

```
void ChangePasswordLink(string t = "") 
{ ChangePasswordControl control = new ChangePasswordControl(Control_Closed); }
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with Telerik... it is a WPF limitation - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx).

Comment: It is also a limitation in Silverlight - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: please show some source code... how is that control instantiated ?

Comment: The code is being invoked by a ICommand ChangePasswordCommand which again is called from a binding in the xaml.
void ChangePasswordLink(string t = "")
        {
            ChangePasswordControl control = new ChangePasswordControl(Control_Closed);
        }

Sry. for the formatting. Not sure how this works :S

Comment: updated your question with the code from your comment... I still don't understand the problem... what exactly is the goal ?

Comment: Thank you. Problem is that I need a parent on my control in order for the behavior to work. Behavior in my case is a on screen keyboard that pops up based on a parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by bringing a parameter with me (holding the parent - or whatever parent for that matter, as long as it is a Parent) all the way from the code behind file to the ViewModel and to the behavior class.

Thanks for your help.